# disable programatically the virtual keyboard on windows 7?

Tags: c#, wpf, multi-touch

How can disable programatically the virtual keyboard on windows 7 ?
I no need the keyboard on my **touch** appz, can someone expalin how disable and enable?
Bets regads.

Answer (score 0):

When you click a Windows Phone 7 TextInput control, the Virtual Keyboard is shown!

Change the property of textbox as seen below:
IsHitTestVisible="True"   (in XAML)
or
textBox1.IsHitTestVisible = false;  (dynamically)

Comment: The question appears to be related to Windows 7, not WP7.

Comment: Hi, im talking of WINDOWS 7, not of windows phone 7 : ) Anyway thankyou for your answer : )